# Minimum Moves to get Lexicographical Smallest Value by Rotating the string

Tags: c++, string, rotation, lexicographic

I'm doing a problem to get the minimum moves it takes to get the smallest lexicographical value of the given string. I first added the string and rotated it to store on the map with it's key as the move. Then I returned the first key of the Map which gives me the maxMoves to get that minimal lexicographic string. Eg: *anadama => nadamaa => adamaan => damaana => amaanad => maanada => aanadam*. Here output = 6, since it takes six rotation to get the string with smallest lexicographic value.

As I run through the submission it says Abort Called or Runtime Error- Message Masked.

Here is my code:

```
int minRotate(string inscription) {

    map<string, int> concatedString;
    int inscriptionLength = inscription.length();
    inscription += inscription;

    int minRotation = 0, roatateNum = 1, temp = 1;   

    //Checking if the given is lexiographically small in number
    if (inscription.empty() || inscription.find_first_not_of(inscription[0]) == string::npos)
        return minRotation;

    for (int i = 1; i <= inscriptionLength; i++) {

        //rotate(inscription.begin(), inscription.begin()+1, inscription.end());
        string tempString = inscription.substr(temp, inscriptionLength);
        concatedString[tempString] = i;
        temp++;
    }

    map<string, int>::iterator it = concatedString.begin();
    minRotation = it->second;

    return minRotation;
}
```

Comment: You *do* remember that array and string indexes are *zero based*? That is, the valid indexes for the string `inscription` are `0` to `inscription.length - 1` (inclusive)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh actually I'm using that to get the no. of characters that I need to take from my inscription to tempString. string.substr(position, # of char);

Comment: If you [debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) you will see that in the last iteration of the loop, `temp` should be equal to `inscriptionLength`, which is out of bounds of the string `inscription`. What do you think happens when you use that as the starting index of the substring?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it's actually the length of characters I'm about to copy. String.substr(position, #of chars);

Comment: And if the "position" is out of bounds of the string? This is what happens with your code. Your variable `temp` will be *out of bounds*. Please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you for the link. I will debug the code and check the error. Actually I used string tempString = inscription.substr(temp, inscriptionLength);   instead of  //rotate(inscription.begin(), inscription.begin()+1, inscription.end());